# Hide figures while copying them into Excel

Tags: excel, matlab, printing, plot, figure

```
for i = 1:max
    fh = figure;
    plot(data);
    print(fh, '-dbitmap');
    xls.Range(figRange).PasteSpecial;
end
```

How can I modify the code above so the figures won't show up while copying them into an Excel sheet?

I have tried

```
set(fh,'Visible','off','CreateFcn','set(plotH(i),''Visible'',''on'')');
```

but did not work out.

Comment: So, 'Application.ScreenUpdating = False' doesn't work?  (PS - don't forget to set to True later.

Comment: I haven't tried it. Can you give me a bit more detail? That dotted notation doesn't look like a traditional MATLAB code.

Comment: That's an Excel bit...I thought you wanted the figures to not display on the Excel side.

Comment: Nah. I want to avoid MATLAB popping up figures one after another while copying and pasting them into the sheet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plot multiple figures in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449896/plot-multiple-figures-in-background)